# Reduction formula for integral $\int 1/(a^2+x^2)^n dx$

Tags: integration

I want to solve the integral $\int 1/(a^2+x^2)^n dx$. I guess this can be solved using the reduction formula as in the case of $\int x^2/(a^2+x^2)^n dx$.
However, I am not able to do it.

Comment: A detailed video with an explanation is available here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6CqoMNrQS4&ab_channel=Math%2CPhysics%2CEngineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many derivations online [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#How_to_find_the_reduction_formula), [2](http://mathhelpforum.com/calculus/76025-stuck-reduction-formula-integrating-x-2-2-n.html)

But this has been derived using differentiation

$$\dfrac{d[x(a^2+x^2)^m]}{dx}=(a^2+x^2)^m+2mx^2(a^2+x^2)^{m-1}$$

$$=(a^2+x^2)^m+2m(x^2+a^2-a^2)(a^2+x^2)^{m-1}$$

If $\displaystyle I_m=\int(a^2+x^2)^m\ dx,$  integrate both sides wrt $x$ to find

$$x(a^2+x^2)^m=I_m(1+2m)-2ma^2I_{m-1}$$

In your case $m=-n$